# SCCM and Powershell -- how do I get an Application's LocalizedDisplayName from PackageID?

Tags: powershell, wmi, sccm, wql

I'm being passed a PackageID.  My query looks like this:

```
select a.LocalizedDisplayName
from SMS_CIContentPackage cp
inner join SMS_Application a on cp.CI_ID = a.CI_ID
where cp.PackageID = 'AMS001D3'
```

When I execute it, I get "Error running query against ROOT\SMS\site_ST1 namespace.  Generic failure".

What am I doing wrong?  I suspect that since PackageID also appears in SMS_Application, but as a lazy-loaded property, this could have something to do with it.

FWIW, once I have that LocalizedDisplayName, I'm going to feed that into the following query.  If there's an easier way to do this, I'm all ears.

```
select SMS_R_System.Name
from  SMS_R_System 
inner join SMS_G_System_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE on SMS_G_System_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId 
where SMS_G_System_INSTALLED_SOFTWARE.ProductName = '{localized name goes here}'
```

The whole point is to find out if a device has been installed, given a Package ID.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try declaring using 'as':

`select a.LocalizedDisplayName from SMS_CIContentPackage as cp inner join SMS_Application as a on cp.CI_ID = a.CI_ID where cp.PackageID = 'AMS001D3'`

I would suggest trying to create your query in the CM console to ensure it's valid etc.

Comment: Alternatively you can remove the shorthand as it's not really necessary -   `select SMS_Application.LocalizedDisplayName from SMS_CIContentPackage inner join SMS_Application on SMS_CIContentPackage.CI_ID = SMS_Application.CI_ID where SMS_CIContentPackage.PackageID = 'AMS001D3'`

Comment: I did some tests and the shorthand only seems to work in the first select not in the join (so best do it like @adam-parsons suggested). no idea why but probably a limitation of wql. As for the whole point of your question. Doing it like this will work with some margin of error. First of all you will also get all systems reported that have installed the same software manually and secondly you will only get results that are delayed by one cycle of hardware inventory (depending on your client settings this could be a week or more)